# Java plugin for installing npm modules

Tags: java, node.js, npm

Hi i am developing a sdk in java, in the sdk the users will provide the node modules names. Is there any way to download those npm packages in java with all its dependencies without forcing the end user to install npm?

Comment: It might be easiest to have your users install NPM then call it as a command from Java.  Just wondering, why are you against having them install NPM?

Answer (score 2):

You can start by studying npm's registry [api](http://registry.npmjs.org/). You can look for packages by appending the package name at the end like this `http://registry.npmjs.org/express` and you just have to parse the returned json and look for the latest tarball urls (if you're looking for the latest distribution, else you can code your plugin to look for specific versions). And then look for the dependencies entries and do the same for them (access the api and download the tarballs). You can actually find more info at their docs.

Comment: yes i looked into it, but the problem is the tarball contains only that module, its dependencies are not present in tat...for ex: if i download the package A then its dependencies B,C are not present in it.

Comment: yes, the json file with the tarball entry also contains the dependencies it requires. you just have to do the same process for each one of them.

Comment: Will it not end in a circular download??

Comment: Well, I don't think package A with dependency package B, will require package A also. If in doubt, you could just check every download if it is just downloading the parent package.

Comment: More broadly you don't need to download something you already downloaded -- pulling a package should be idempotent. If you already have it you don't need to find its dependencies since they should already have been there.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to take a look at this java library: https://github.com/OrienteerBAP/JNPM

Along with native Java API to work with NPM it also provides Command Line Interface, transparent CDN-like access to NPM resources via Servlet for example and maven plugin to get NPM resources and pack within your java library (lightweight replacement of WebJars)